# free memory used for struct in C but fails (code from C Primer Plus 6th Edition)

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

I run the code from Listing 17.2, P781, C Primer Plus 6th Edition.

```
/* films2.c -- using a linked list of structures */    
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>   /* has the malloc prototype */    
#include <string.h>   /* has the strcpy prototype */    
#define TSIZE 45      /* size of array to hold title */                                                                                                                  

struct film {    
    char title[TSIZE];    
    int rating;    
    struct film *next;  /* points to next struct in list */    
};    

char *s_gets(char *st, int n);    


int main(void)    
{    
    struct film *head = NULL;    
    struct film *prev, *current;    
    char input[TSIZE];    

    /* Gather and store information */    
    puts("Enter first movie title:");    
    while (s_gets(input, TSIZE) != NULL && input[0] != '\0') {    
        current = (struct film *) malloc(sizeof(struct film));    
        if (head == NULL)   /* first structure */    
            head = current;    
        else   /* subseqent structures */    
            prev->next = current;    
        current->next = NULL;    
        strcpy(current->title, input);    
        puts("Enter your rating <0-10>:");    
        scanf("%d", &current->rating);    
        while (getchar() != '\n')    
            continue;    
        puts("Enter next movie title (empty line to stop):");    
        prev = current;    
    } 

    /* show list of movies */    
    if (head == NULL)    
        printf("No data entered.");    
    else    
        printf("Here is the movie list:\n");    
    current = head;    
    while (current != NULL) {
        printf("Movie: %s     Rating: %d\n",
                current->title, current->rating);
        current = current->next;
    }

    /* Program done, so free allocated memory */
    current = head;
    while (current != NULL) {
        free(current);
        printf("Movie: %s, Rating: %d\n",                                                                                                                                
                current->title, current->rating);
        current = current->next;
    }
    printf("Bye!\n");

    return 0;
}

char *s_gets(char *st, int n)
{
    char *ret_val;
    char *find;

    ret_val = fgets(st, n, stdin);
    if (ret_val) {
        find = strchr(st, '\n');  // look for newline
        if (find)    // if the address is not NULL,
            *find = '\0';    // place a null character there
        else
            while (getchar() != '\n')
                continue;      // dispose of rest of line
    }
    return ret_val;
}
```

My question is that after `free(current)`, `current->title` and `current->rating` still is there, and `current->next` is not `NULL`. I don't know why.

Comment: Freeing `current` does not make it `NULL`. It simply can't change it as it is passed by value. It is just making it to point to an invalid location. Dereferencing it is UB.

Comment: Oh, this is a code from a book? Throw it away.

Comment: yes the book is wrong. After calling `free` you can never touch that memory again in any way. If you do the computer is allowed to explode. Most won't, but the Deathstation 9000 certainly would.

Comment: This book was originally published in 1984 and while it was perhaps a good reference at the time, it's woefully out of date now if this code is still present in it. The casual "don't worry it's fine" method of writing sloppy C code no longer works.

Comment: @tadman: The 6th edition was published in 2013. If this code is in the 6th edition, it needs to be reported as an error. Neither gcc nor clang detects the error, so it's not *too* surprising that it wasn't caught -- but valgrind does catch it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Why `printf` function could print correct values after making `current` point to an invalid location?

Comment: @KeithThompson Maybe this book is different, but a lot of old books get these very minor updates that never address serious problems like this, just typos and such.

Comment: @KeithThompson@tadman I am so sorry for my mistake. The original code does contain `printf` function. I found the loop for freeing memory is strange, so I add the `printf` function to detect whether the free function works. However, after adding it, it still works. I am confused with `free` function. How does `free` work? Which memory does `free` function deallocate?

Comment: @mathsyouth: `free` makes memory available for further allocation. It does not (necessarily) make it impossible to access it. Accessing freed memory has *undefined behavior*. It's up to you, the programmer, to avoid doing that; the implementation probably won't help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable is still available for use but the space allocated isn't so you will have undefined behavior.
It can work now but it can crash later.
A good practice is to set your pointer to NULL after freeing it.

Answer (score 3):

At least this loop is incorrect

```
current = head;
while (current != NULL) {
    free(current);
    printf("Movie: %s, Rating: %d\n",                                                                                                                                
            current->title, current->rating);
    current = current->next;
}
```

there should be

```
current = head;
while (current != NULL) {
    printf("Movie: %s, Rating: %d\n",                                                                                                                                
            current->title, current->rating);
    struct film *tmp = current;
    current = current->next;
    free(tmp);
}
```

Otherwise you are trying to use an invalid deleted pointer.

Comment: Use-after-free is a pretty egregious mistake to make, especially when teaching.

Comment: Thanks for your point. However, I don't understand why it still works when I am trying to use an invalid deleted pointer. "works" means `printf`function still prints the values of variables.

Comment: @mathsyouth: That's the nature of undefined behavior. The *worst* thing that can happen is that the code appears to "work".

Answer (score 1):

The code is incorrect as mentionedbin other answers.

On one of the subsequent pages the author does show a correct linked list freeing function. He says

> The code saves the address of the next node because the call to `free()`, in principle, may make the contents of the current node (the one pointed to by `*plist`) no longer available.

While technically correct, this passage disqualifies the author as a C instructor. Here's the corrected passage.

> The code saves the address of the next node because the call to free() **makes** the contents of the current node (the one pointed to by `*plist`) no longer available, **and accessing it is undefined behaviour**.

Apparently the author never ever mentions the term "undefined behaviour". This is unacceptable in any serious C textbook.